# .NET Forms Authentication and CurrentContext.User

Tags: .net, forms-authentication

If I call

```
FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
```

with a user logged in (with `createPersistentCookie` set to false on sign in) should I expect

```
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated
```

to be false?

It isn't, and `Identity.Name` still has a value. Is this right?

If this is normal behaviour, what do I need to do to remove all trace of a logged in user?

**Edit:** Is there someway to do what is necessary without doing a `Response.Redirect`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [FormsAuthentication.SignOut](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.signout.aspx) method removes the forms-authentication ticket from the browser, so you need to first redirect and then query the `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` property.

Comment: is redirecting the only option?

Comment: Well, as you are calling the `FormsAuthentication.SignOut` method yourself you already know in the current request that the user has been signed out. As far as the subsequent requests are concerned the cookie will be cleared and the `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` property will be reflected.

Answer (score 1):

Call

```
Response.Redirect(FormsAuthentication.LoginUrl);
```